# Running script and defining object value in terminal window

Tags: perl

When I run Perl scripts, I open up the Terminal window on my Mac and write "`perl test1.pl`" after moving to the folder containing the Perl script.

Often I find myself wanting to run the same Perl many times, usually at the same time, but with very minor changes.

For example say this Perl script "`test1.pl`" looks like this:

```
$year = 2001;
<rest of code that uses $year>
```

I want to execute "test1.pl" where $year = 2001, where $year = 2002, etc. To do this I usually run the script where $year = 2001, then adjust the script so $year = 2002, save, open new terminal window, run again, repeat.

Is there a way to submit the Perl script by designating in the terminal window the value for `$year`?

I'm thinking something like:

```
perl test1.pl, $year = 2001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way (of many ways) to do this is:

```
my $year = (@ARGV) ? shift : 2001;
```

Then run it as:

```
perl test1.pl 2002
```

2001 will be the defualt if you don't specify a year on the command line.  See also: `perldoc -v @ARGV`

Comment: I tend to use (of many ways, indeed!)  `my $year = shift // 2001;`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give arguments from command line i would highly suggest using `Getopt::Long` module. You can use code in this way

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $year = 2001;

GetOptions (
      'year|y=i' => \$year
);

print "$year\n";
```

You will call this script in this way `perl test1.pl -y 2002` or `perl test1.pl -y=2002` or `perl test1.pl --year=2002` or `perl test1.pl --year 2002`.

Default value of `$year` will be 2001 and if script is called as `perl test1.pl` the 2001 will be printed.

Also `i` in `year|y=i` means that perl will be expecting you to provide integer type and non-int type will generate error here.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**

Both answers can solve your problem. But i prefer using `Getopt` more than the other approach. Reason for this are :-

1. Using `ARGV` approach user has to be specific in position of arguments. Instead in this approach one can put arguments at any position. `perl a.pl -y 2 -z 3` is same as `per a.pl -z 3 -y 2`.
2. Give more confidence to user as he/she knows which argument is meant for what purpose (given argument name are relevant).
3. If you are making something for other to use then this way help a lot. Using `help` as argument and explaining them using such argument is way better than explaining them to put this argument in first position and that argument in second.

I think that both way of approaching to your problem will technically solve the issue but personally i prefer my approach. It is more clean and really good if you are making programs with lot of options.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the response! Seems useful. What's the difference between your suggestion sand the other answer?

Comment: @user1500158 I have explained difference between them in my answer. I hope this will help you. Please tell me if you need any other explanation.